# How to understand the timestamp in the mysql binlog?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, binlog

the binlog always looks like this:

```
#140105 18:49:33 server id 2  end_log_pos 354   Query   thread_id=1     exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1388918973/*!*/;
/* some SQL statement */
/*!*/;
```

The illustration from the official site is :

> In the first line, the number following at indicates the starting
>   position of the event in the binary log file.
>
> The second line starts with a date and time indicating when the
>   statement started on the server where the event originated. For
>   replication, this timestamp is propagated to slave servers. server id
>   is the server_id value of the server where the event originated.
>   end_log_pos indicates where the next event starts (that is, it is the
>   end position of the current event + 1). thread_id indicates which
>   thread executed the event. exec_time is the time spent executing the
>   event, on a master server. On a slave, it is the difference of the end
>   execution time on the slave minus the beginning execution time on the
>   master. The difference serves as an indicator of how much replication
>   lags behind the master. error_code indicates the result from executing
>   the event. Zero means that no error occurred.

It said **"The second line starts with a date and time"**, it seemed this format of datetime is quite different from the "SET TIMESTAMP" clause, where the number means the seconds from 1970-1-1, but what is the "**#140105** 18:49:33" means, that's date of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

140105 means YYMMDD.

05 JAN(01) 2014

obviously 18:49:33 is the time